# C# Entity Framework recursive hierarchy query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'll first show my case in order to explain the question - I created a role and tasks architecture in SQL Server that looks like this:

[image]

I have 2 main tables, `Roles` and `Tasks`, and 2 link tables.

I have generated this model (using Entity Framework generator) to Entity Framework classes in C# and I got those classes:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> ChildTask { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> ParentTask { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get all the tasks names of one role and I'm having trouble because task has self hierarchy.

Can I do it using entity framework and without go over each child manually/SQL Server stored procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "I'm having trouble"? You shoud be able to get a Role's Tasks by `Role.Tasks`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to get all the related task names for a given role.
So for example Role.Task will give me the direct related task,
but the related task can have child task (Role.Task.ChildTask) and the child task can have another multiple ChildTask (Role.Task.ChildTask.ChildTask) And I want to get all all the Name property of task for example on all this hirarchy for A given role id

Comment: Why are you using many-to-many relationships here?  Can a Task really have many Parent Tasks and Many Roles?

Comment: Yes, A task can be child of multiple other task and parent task have many child task. And same for role, can have many linked task and one task can be linked to many roles

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively with the help of `LazyLoading`:

```
public List<string> GetTaskNames(Task task, List<string> tasks = null)
{
    if(tasks == null);
        tasks = new List<string>();
    tasks.Add(task.Name);

    foreach(var child in task.ChildTask)
       GetTaskNames(child, tasks);

    return tasks;
}

var role = context.Roles.Find(roleId);
var names = role.Tasks.SelectMany(x => GetTaskNames(x)).Distinct().ToList();
```