# EF Core: Counting the Number of Multi-Level Children of an Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class Entity {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    virtual Entity Parent { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<Entity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Given a certain entity id: `theId`, I wish to count the number of its children, its children's children, its children's children's children, etc..

One naive way to do it is as follows:

```
var count = dbContext.Where(x => x.Id == theId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .Count();
```

The problem is that I need to increase the number `SelectMany`s to the max depth of children I have, which is not practical. I feel like this is not possible using EntityFramework and I have to use SQL procedures, but I wanted to ask just to make sure of this.

P.S. I'm using EF Core.

Comment: that would be difficult, as you will need to do a [recursion](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=recursion). i am not aware trivial way to do recursion on entity framework. you have to load the entire rows into memory and walks from there as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354734/4648586) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138605/c-sharp-entity-framework-recursive-hierarchy-query), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987365/implementing-recursive-property-loading-in-ef-core).

Comment: @BagusTesa There are a couple of techniques to achieve this, the issue however is that I want to load many entities ids and their respective counts. I'd like to be able to do that using lowest number of queries.

Comment: Best strategy I know is using left and right values, like this place here:https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ you have to write custom queries checking for left and right values because there is no way that EF can do anything by magic in a hieracy

Comment: @ThomasKoelle Thanks, I had a look at it, it's an interesting approach, though it would be challenging if the hierarchy needs to be updated. I posted a solution to this, that have, I guess, less overhead when dealing with hierarchy updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution that works for my case, here it goes: I added another property to `Entity`; I called it `Hierarchy`. Its value can be `000`, `001`, `002`, ..., `00y`, `00z`, `010`, ..., `zzy`, ..., `zzz`. In other words, it is a 3-digit base-62 number (but stored as a string). Additionally, the `Hierarchy` of a child entity will be prefixed with the `Hierarchy` of its parent. So for example if we have a parent entity `ParentEntity` with `Hierarchy` of `001`, which has a child entity `ChildEntity` with `Hierarchy` of `000`, the child entity's final value for `Hierarchy` would be: `001000`. This way, if I want to get a parent's children in all levels, I would just do this:

```
dbContext.Entities.Count(x => x.Hierarchy.StartsWith(parentEntity.Hierarchy))
```

The limitation to this solution is the limited number of children for each parent, in this case it is 62*62*62 = 238,328. This number is more than enough for my case, but can be increased by increasing the size of the `Hierarchy` field, e.g., 4-digit as opposed to 3-digit number.

Of course you'd have to be careful when updating the entities; whenever an entity's level has changed, update the `Hierarchy` accordingly. Also, I created an index for the `Hierarchy` field in the database for faster search.